# Where to place "Thank You" in end of email?

Tags: word-choice, email

I keep getting differing opinions on this. I usually close my emails as follows:

> ... <end of body>. 
>
> Thank You.
> Sincerely, 
> <designation>

However, I was told by quite a few peers that the **Thank You** was supposed to be as follows or better not include it in the first place:

> ... <end of body>. Thank You.
>
> Sincerely, 
> <designation>

I do feel like I need to include the **Thank You** in official emails to people such as my professors or higher officials, so where exactly would it be wise to place the **Thank You**?

Answer (score 1):

There may be differences here depending on region. I am answering this from a UK perspective.

There's no rule as far as I'm aware that you should even use "thank you" at the end of an email. To be honest, it seems rather strange to me unless you are actually thanking someone for something. It could even be perceived as an expression of impatience/annoyance.  I'd avoid it.

Usually, I would end an email with "Kind regards", or "Regards", or even something much less formal like "See you soon, "Take care", for example if I'm writing to a close friend.

In the UK, "Yours sincerely" is usually reserved for formal letters when we know the addressee's name, and "Yours faithfully" for formal letters when the addressee's name is unknown - i.e. when a letter begins with Dear Sir/Madam. However these standard closing salutations are not technically required for emails. There's nothing to stop you from using them in an email, but personally I wouldn't. It's just a bit too formal, and might be seen as a bit old fashioned.

Comment: In British letter usage, it is traditional to close with 'Yours sincerely' when you started with title + name (e.g. Dear Mrs Jones, Lady Brown, Sir Peter, Lord Bloggs, etc) but 'Yours faithfully' when you started with 'Dear  Sir', 'Dear Madam' or 'Dear Sir or Madam'.

Comment: Yes. I know, that's what I meant. I'll add a little edit to make it clearer.

Comment: I think many people these days don't worry about it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - yes that's true, most people won't care.

Answer (score 0):

I think, and my organisation does, that emails should be polite, certainly, but importantly, brief and to the point. We would not thank someone merely for reading the email. A common format is

```
Dear Mr Jones

Thank you for your email (if it is a reply to one from the sender). 

The body of the email here.

Regards (or Best regards)

Michael Harvey
Legal Finance Controller
Acme Law LLC
123 High St
Bristol 
BS1 1JJ
0117 123 3456
```